# Não está a imprimir string

Tags: python, string, stack

Bom dia, alguem me pode ajudar?

> Pretende-se o desenvolvimento da função `invert_pal(st)` que recebe como parâmetro uma string `st` e retorne como resultado a mesma string em que cada palavra ficou com as letras invertidas.
> Por exemplo, `invert_pal(“Eu gosto de programar”)` deveria retornar a string `“uE otsog ed ramargorp”`.
> Na resolução deste exercício deve obrigatoriamente utilizar uma stack *(pode considerar a existência da classe stack não necessitando de a desenvolver)*.

```
Lf= []
st= (input ("Introduza a palavra: "))
L= list (st)
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    
    def top(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]
    
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

def invert_pal ():
    inverter= Stack ()
    for i in L:
        inverter.push(i)
    while not inverter.isEmpty():
        y= inverter.pop()
        Lf.append(y)
    print (str(Lf))
                
a= invert_pal()
print (a)
```

Comment: Nas últimas linhas, você exibe a variável `a`, que é o retorno de `invert_pal`, porém a função não possui retorno. Isso não parece certo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um script que seja capaz de receber uma `Frase` e retornar esta frase com as letras de cada palavra revertida, isto é, receba "Eu gosto de programar" e retorne "uE otsog ed ramargorp".

Uma das formas mais eficientes para resolver este problema é utilizando listas. Para isso podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def invert_pal(fra):
    return [i[::-1] for i in fra]


frase = input('Digite a frase desejada: ').split()

print(*invert_pal(frase))
```

Observe que quando executamos este script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite a frase desejada:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a frase completa e pressionar `Enter`. Em seguida, esta frase será armazenada em uma lista, sendo a mesma passada como parâmetro para a função `invert_pal(fra)`. Chegando lá, esta lista será remontada, na qual cada palavra da mesma será revertida.

OBS: A reversão das palavras são executadas por intermédio do list comprehension no seguinte código:

```
[i[::-1] for i in fra]
```

**O que este código está fazendo?** Este código está percorrendo cada um dos elementos da lista `fra` e revertendo suas letras, ou seja, remontando cada uma das palavras com suas letras revertidas.

Por último, será exibido o retorno da função. Retorno este formado pelo desempacotamento da lista formada pelas palavras revertidas.

**Testando o código:**

Ao executar o código, digitamos...

```
Eu gosto de programar
```

... e pressionamos `Enter`. Em seguida receberemos como resultado:

```
uE otsog ed ramargorp
```

Comment: Muito bom o seu código mas creio que o split() poderia ficar embutido na função invert_pal()

Answer (score 1):

Toda vez que for resolver um problema primeira coisa que deve fazer é decodificar a mensagem proposta com a finalidade em descobrir o que está sendo requerido. Nesse processo não tenha medo de grifar o texto em busca de informações que considerar relevantes.

> Pretende-se o **desenvolvimento da função `invert_pal(st)`** que **recebe como
> parâmetro uma `string st`** e retorne como **resultado a mesma string em que
> cada palavra ficou com as letras invertidas**.
> Por exemplo,
> `invert_pal(“Eu gosto de programar”)` deveria retornar a string `“uE otsog ed ramargorp”`.
> Na resolução deste exercício deve **obrigatoriamente utilizar uma stack**
> (pode **considerar a existência da classe stack não necessitando de a desenvolver**).

Então podemos identificar os seguintes requisitos:

- O objetivo é desenvolvimento da função `invert_pal()`.
- `invert_pal()` deve receber como parâmetro uma `string st`.
- O retorno de `invert_pal(st)` deve ser a `string st` invertida.
- A inversão deve ser feita por meio de uma pilha(stack).
- irrelevância na implementação da pilha.

Conhecidos os requisitos é possível concluir que o foco deve ser a construção da função `invert_pal()` que obrigatoriamente deve receber uma `string st` e operar obrigatoriamente por meio de uma pilha esse parâmetro `string st` de forma que obrigatoriamente o resultado dessa operação seja a `string st` invertida e que esse seja o retorno de `invert_pal(st)`.

```
#Define a função invert_pal dotada de um parâmetro st, evitando o uso de variáveis globais.
def invert_pal(st):
    pilha = Stack()                     #Cria-se uma pilha que receberá os caracteres de st.
    resultado = []                      #Cria-se uma lista que receberá os caracteres desempilhados da pilha.
    #Para cada caractere da entrada st...
    for c in st:
        pilha.push(c)                   #...empilhe dado caractere.
    #Enquanto a pilha não estiver vazia...
    while not pilha.isEmpty:
        resultado.append(pilha.pop())   #...desempilhe os caracteres da pilha em resultado
    #Junte todos os caracteres do resultado em uma string e a retorne.
    return "".join(resultado)
```

Juntando a função `invert_pal(st)` em um exemplo testável:

```
#Como o exercício não determinou uma implementação específica para a pilha decidi
# a implementar não como uma fachada para um objeto List mas como uma derivação dessa classe 
# evitando assim a reimplementação desnecessária de métodos, ex: pop(). 
class Stack(list):
    @property
    def isEmpty(self):              #Retorna True se a pilha estiver vazia.
        return self.size == 0
    
    @property
    def top(self):                  #Não foi utilizada na resolução. Retorna o topo da pila sem remover.
        return self[-1]
        
    @property
    def size(self):                 #Devolve o tamanho da pilha.
        return len(self)
    
    def push(self, item):           #Empilha um item.
        self.append(item)

def invert_pal(st):
    pilha = Stack()
    resultado = []
    for c in st:
        pilha.push(c)
    while not pilha.isEmpty:
        resultado.append(pilha.pop())
    return "".join(resultado)
                
a = invert_pal(input("Introduza a palavra: "))
print(a)
```

Resultando:

```
Introduza a palavra: Eu gosto de programar
ramargorp ed otsog uE
```

Answer (score 0):

1-A função invert_pal deve retornar a string ao contrario usando return, mas: Nas últimas linhas, você exibe a variável a, que é o retorno de invert_pal, porém a função não possui retorno

Codigo:

```py
Lf= []
st= (input ("Introduza a palavra: "))
L= list (st)
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    
    def top(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]
    
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

def invert_pal ():
    inverter= Stack ()
    for i in L:
        inverter.push(i)
    while not inverter.isEmpty():
        y= inverter.pop()
        Lf.append(y)
    print (str(Lf))
    return str(Lf)
                
a= invert_pal()
print (a)
```